# Verifying triangular inequality for $\big(\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}\big)^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

How is it possible to verify that the triangular inequality holds (or not) for the following:

$||x,y||^*:=\big(\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}\big)^2$ where $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$

Edit: I already found counter example to show the inequality is not satisfied and also founda a "graphical point of view" plotting the level sets for:
$(\sqrt{|x+\tilde{x}|}+\sqrt{|y+\tilde{y}|})^2$ and for $(\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|})^2+(\sqrt{|\tilde{x}|}+\sqrt{|\tilde{y}|})^2$ but I'd like to have a "direct computation".

Comment: I don't think its possible to give a better answer than what Jose has written if you don't clarify what you mean by "direct computation"?

Comment: I was thinking maybe from $(\sqrt{|x+\tilde{x}|}+\sqrt{|y+\tilde{y}|})^2$ to derive $(\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|})^2+(\sqrt{|\tilde{x}|}+\sqrt{|\tilde{y}|})^2$ by some inequalities but maybe it would be a possible way just if the triangular inequality were true

Comment: There are points where the triangle inequality /is/ satisfied, for instance along the line $x=0$. You need to find just one point where it doesn't work, and for that see Jose's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Compute:

- $\bigl\lVert(0,0)-(1,0)\bigr\rVert^*$;
- $\bigl\lVert(1,0)-(1,1)\bigr\rVert^*$;
- $\bigl\lVert(0,0)-(1,1)\bigr\rVert^*$.

Comment: See the edit, thank you